# Is the vector field conservative?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

$$\mathbf{v}=\left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},0\right)$$ is a vector field.

If we need to find $$\iint_{S}^{}(\nabla\times\mathbf{v})\cdot d\mathbf{a}$$ over a hemispherical surface placed on the $x$-$y$ plane centred at the origin, is it zero?

However if we use Stoke's theorem and calculate the line integral it gives a value $2\pi$. What's going on here?

Comment: This vector field is undefined at $(0,0,z)$.

Comment: Hmm... so that means 2π is the residue here? And so the vector field is not conservative then?

Comment: @Wojowu What do you mean by that? As I read it, the first two components of $v$ do not depend on $z$ and the third one vanishes. The first two components of its curl vanish and the third one $4xy/{({x^2}+{y^2})^2}$ does not depend on $z$ but does not vanish.

Comment: @Urgje At a point $(x,y,z)$ for which $x=y=0$ (so that the point is of the form $(0,0,z)$) the value vector field involves division by zero, hence isn't well-defined. Indeed, the components don't depend on $z$, but aren't defined for $x=y=0$.

Comment: @Wojowu That is true but it seems there are proper limits.

Comment: @Urgje There aren't. Taking e.g. $x=y$ there is no limit as $x,y\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, I am convinced.

Answer (score 0):

Even though $\nabla\times\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$, the domain of the field $\mathbf{v}$ is $D = \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \left\{(0,0,z) ~|~ z \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus the $z$-axis. $D$ is not a simply connected region: for example, the boundary for your hemisphere surrounds the $z$-axis and cannot be continuously shrunk to a point while remaining in $D$. For any closed curve $X$ in $D$ which *can* be so shrunk, we have $\displaystyle\oint_X\mathbf{v}\cdot d\mathbf{r} = 0$

Comment: Thanks! So, anyways just for the sake of result verification, in this case the surface integral of the curl is 2π then?

Comment: @Dirac93: I don't know, I'm afraid! If Stokes' theorem applied, the equivalent line integral indeed gives $2\pi$, but for Stokes' theorem to apply $\mathbf{v}$ needs to be a continuous vector field with continuous first partial derivatives over a region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which contains your hemisphere $S$. My grasp of continuity bad enough to keep me from speculating on what's going on near the $z$-axis. I don't know how to treat the surface integral in that region from basic principles.

Comment: Since the field spikes at the origin, can't we employ a Dirac delta function? So if we have the surface integral of a two dimensional dirac delta, we have a constant times 1 which here should be 2π. And hence, Stoke's theorem remains valid.